# dotnet pack not including build artifacts

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying to publish my project to a nuget package using dotnet pack from within visual studio 2015. My project.json is as follows:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.6.6-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.1",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.0.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {},
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0-*"
        }
      },
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postcompile": [
      "dotnet pack --no-build --configuration %compile:Configuration% --output %Builds%"
    ]
  }
}
```

`dotnet pack...` packages up my project into a nuget package as a postbuild event and puts it in the directory defined by the environment directory `Builds` (obviously I want --no-build in there otherwise I'd get into an infinte loop).

The problem is that when I unzip the package it doesn't contain the dll.

I've tried deleting the obj folder (where I believe nuget temporarily stores the artifacts), deleted the output etc. and I can't get the package to include the dll.

I had it working before and changed nothing so I don't understand why it's not working now.

Comment: Looking at your dependencies it's not clear if you are building a library or an application. Having code for both outputs me a package containing "netcoreapp1.0" folder with a .dll file, and "net451" folder containing an .exe file within a "lib" folder. 
Can you clarify what you are building and what folders/files you get inside the package?

Comment: I'm trying to build a library. As far as I understand you need to add things to fake being an application in order for the dotnet core database scaffolding to work.

It looks like you're right though, I have a bin folder in my output directory that has what you describe, the package itself, however, only contains an `_rels` folder with an `.rels` file in it, a `[Content_Types].xml` and a nuspec file, it's missing the dll. I can however see the dll in the output directory.

Comment: I am not sure why dotnet pack would not work for you, however as a workaround (temporary?) I can suggest including nuget.exe into solution and a nuspec file, and call nuget.exe pack manually. You can specify what has to be included where in the nuspec file.

Comment: If it helps to identify the issue I believe that the contents of the nuget package _should_ show up in the obj folder (as it's used for temporary storage, I believe) but all that's in there is an empty debug folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that it's because I changed the output directory in the xproj file, when I changed it back it started creating the package correctly